# Detect device change (desktop, tablet or mobile) in Customizer

Tags: theme-customizer, callbacks

In the Theme Customizer preview I am using Modernizr to include certain classes that change the page styles. If I understand it correctly, changing the device type to tablet or mobile only changes the window size but doesn't trigger any callback or page reload.

Right now, the only way I can think of is adding a resize listener in my preview script and see which device do the new window dimensions match.

I would like to know if there is a built-in filter or way to trigger a callback in the preview window so I can include the correct class for each device view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way to accomplish this would be to send messages from the Customizer controls pane window to the Customizer preview window when the `wp.customize.previewedDevice` value changes.

So you can enqueue a script at the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` action with `customize-controls` as its script dependency that does:

```
(function ( api ) {
    api.bind( 'ready', function() {
        function sendPreviewedDevice() {
            api.previewer.send( 'previewed-device', api.previewedDevice.get() );
        }

        // Send the initial previewed device when preview is ready.
        api.previewer.bind( 'ready', sendPreviewedDevice );

        // Send the previewed device whenever it changes.
        api.previewedDevice.bind( sendPreviewedDevice );
    });
}) ( wp.customize );
```

That handles sending the message from the controls to the preview. Then you need a separate script in the preview to listen for the messages from the pane. Enqueue a separate script in `wp_enqueue_scripts` if `is_customize_preview()` such as the following:

```
(function ( api, $ ) {
    api.bind( 'preview-ready', function() {
        var previousPreviewedDevice = null;

        // Listen for a previewed-device message.
        api.preview.bind( 'previewed-device', function( previewedDevice ) {
            var body = $( document.body );
            if ( previousPreviewedDevice ) {
                body.removeClass( previousPreviewedDevice );
            }
            body.addClass( previewedDevice );
            previousPreviewedDevice = previewedDevice;
        });
    });
}) ( wp.customize, jQuery );
```

The result is that the device being previewed will appear as a class on the preview window's `body` element, for example `tablet`.

I've pushed this up into a standalone plugin in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/b2fdf9347c8441ba9933569b15e2faa7

For more information, see also our [Customizer Responsive Server-Side Components Device Preview](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customizer-responsive-device-preview) plugin and its corresponding writeup: [Previewing Themes with Adaptive Designs in the Customizer](https://make.xwp.co/2016/10/29/previewing-themes-with-adaptive-designs-in-the-customizer/). This is probably closer to what you may be wanting since it seems you're not implementing a purely responsive theme.